# Sending NGINX logs to a remote syslog server

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nginx, logs

How to write Nginx configuration on `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to forward Nginx logs to another server?

I write this configuration for `rsyslog` but I think it's not completely right:

[image]

Comment: @Nmath I can circumvent your comment based on reading this post because what OP wants to do is make nginx report to a remote syslog server.  Which they can't do with `rsyslogd` because NGINX doesn't use the local syslog system to report things to file.  My answer provides this answer to them for both WSL and non-WSL.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question **as asked** is simply: **You don't.**  NGINX doesn't use the local syslog mechanisms to store its logs in files - it opens them and handles them directly.

NGINX does *not* use rsyslog or any of the other logging mechanisms to store its log files.  NGINX opens them **directly**, bypassing `rsyslogd` and the rest of the syslog daemons.

NGINX however *does* have the mechanism to report to syslog directly.

The examples of this (from http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) are as such to implement:

```
# This will enable debug level logging and send to the remote syslog server at 
# 192.168.1.1 on UDP port 514
error_log syslog:server=192.168.1.1 debug;

# This logs to a syslog server listening on a local UNIX socket.
access_log syslog:server=unix:/var/log/nginx.sock,nohostname;

# This logs to a remote syslog server at IPv6 address 2001:db8::1 on UDP port 12345
# using the reporting facility 'local7', tagging it as nginx, and logging with INFO
# level logging, using the default 'combined' format for logging.
access_log syslog:server=[2001:db8::1]:12345,facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=info combined;
```

The details of what each argument are is in the linked document.

Most likely you'll want to use this though:

```
error_log syslog:server=192.168.1.3,facility=local7;
access_log syslog:server=192.168.1.3,facility=local7,severity=info;
```

Just make sure you configure the remote syslog server to process the `local7` facility/channel accordingly for NGINX entries.

Answer (score 0):

@thomas-ward gave a great answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me... after a bit of digging I used the following syntax for `access_log` and `error_log` in  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,tag=nameThisSomethingElse,nohostname,severity=info combined_realip;
error_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,tag=nameThisSomethingElse,nohostname,severity=error;
```

... obviously changing `nameThisSomethingElse`.

This also required the `combined_realip` in `nginx.conf`:

```
log_format combined_realip '$http_x_real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Then in my rsyslog config i created `/etc/rsyslog.d/60-nameThisSomething.conf`:

```
echo "nameThisSomethingElse.* @@1.2.3.4:514" > /etc/rsyslog.d/60-nginx.conf
```

... obviously changing `1.2.3.4` to my syslog server.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The ideal way to do this is via a log forwarder like [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/) or [vector](https://vector.dev) which will watch the log files created by nginx, tail them and send them to the appropriate destination. You would run fluentbit/vector as a service on the same machine as nginx. Both of them are super lightweight so you should be fine on resources front.

You could use https://github.com/zinclabs/zincobserve as a destination on another server to receive logs.

ps: I am from zincobserve team.